# Appcelerator titanium android crash

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-android

In android (again) i received following error and app stops working when i go to a screen :

```
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: (main) [629,72636] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy; Titanium 6.0.1,2016/12/19 16:51,undefined
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleMessage(TiViewProxy.java:237)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
[ERROR] :  D/        (  691): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xdd0a53a0, tid 3809
[INFO] :   Process: Sending signal. PID: 3733 SIG: 9
[INFO] :   D/        ( 3814): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xee930780, tid 3814
[INFO] :   D/        ( 3814): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf3d7c940, tid 3852
```

I don't know what the error message means, why i receive "HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf3d7c940, tid 3852" ?

**DETAILS ADDED :**
On my code i have something like this :

```
<Alloy>
    <Window>
        <Require type="view" id="dashboard_center" src="mydashboard/myprofile" />
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

And in my profile controller i have somewhere :

```
.... FROM REMOTE ...
_.each(response, function(mission, key, obj) {  
    $.block.add(Alloy.createController("common/user_profile", obj[i]).getView()); 
i++;});
```

**LAST UPDATE ...**

I seems my issue is from this loop when i try to add an object to a view (working on ios), but fails on android, any help ? :

```
var s = [];
var star_style = $.createStyle({
    classes : 'star'
});

for (var i = 0; i < total_notes; i++) {
    var star = Ti.UI.createImageView({
        image : 'images/stars.png',
        classes : ["star"],
    });
    star.applyProperties(star_style);
    s.push(star);
}

$.stars_container.add(s);
```

When i comment the last line ($.stars_container.add(s)), the crash go away.
Thanks for help.

Comment: it seems you're trying to use an object as a `Ti.UI.View` component

Comment: Are you using liveview?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment, i'm not using liveview, what do you mean by "it seems you're trying to use an object as a Ti.UI.View component" ? i updated my question for more details, i note that my app works fine on ios.

Answer (score 0):

This is very much related to the method `someView.addView(something);` where `something` means not a Ti.UI element.

Try to validate that everything that you add into a `Ti.UI.View` is another `Ti.UI` component.